# Redirect if user is not author of post they are viewing

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress as the backend to my website where people can create accounts and write posts. Posts should only be viewable by the author of the post. I've handled this in most places on the site, for example, the query for the list of posts:

---

```
$wpb_all_query = new wp_query(array('author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));`
```

---

I'm now realizing that people can see posts by other authors if they manually enter the URL of the post (which would be easy to guess). How can I redirect people if they are not the author of a post they are trying to view?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has provide core function for check that is user is auther or not..

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!is_author()) {
    //The user has the "author" role
}
```

I hope its helpfull to you

Comment: Thanks. I used this as inspiration and ended up with:

`if ($current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  { //showpage}`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is ,

```
$required_capability = 'edit_others_posts';
$redirect_to = '';
function redirect_user() {      

    global $required_capability, $redirect_to;
    if (!current_user_can($required_capability)) {              
        if ($redirect_to == '') { $redirect_to = get_option('home');}              
        wp_redirect($redirect_to,302);              
     }      
}

add_action('init','redirect_user',0);
```

Change the capability to read view edit , etc.. whatever you want to apply for the current user.